# fume (n) instead of smoke (n)?

Tags: differences

Are the following example sentences not wrong? Shouldn't we use "fume" instead of "smoke":

> ‘Those averse to cigarette or cigar ***smoke*** may be floored by the cloud of nicotine in the downstairs bar.’

.

> ‘Cigarette ***smoke*** not only causes cancer and asthma but causes the skin to lose its elasticity, hence wrinkles around the outh.’

.

> ‘Cigarette ***smoke*** and nicotine cause the heart rate to raise by 15 to 25 beats per minute.’

.

> ‘Cigarette ***smoke*** contains a range of xenobiotics, including oxidants and free radicals that can increase lipid peroxidation.’

Source of this sentences: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/smoke

Why do I think, that "smoke" is wrong here? 
In all these examples, the focus is not on the visual appearance of the smoke, but on the health-damaging smell or the unpleasant scent.

Answer (score 4):

The literal meanings of words, or rather the explicit conscious logical formal denotation of a word is not always how it is used.

Though 'fumes' may be technically more accurate (all these instances refer to the non-visible chemicals that travel beyond the visible cloud of smoke, and fumes are often invisible in comparison to smoke), it is more understandable to refer to the stuff as cigarette smoke.

Also it is just the way it is spoken of, it is the natural idiom, so much so that really, 'smoke' and 'fumes', though not exact synonyms, are interchangeable here, and people just say 'smoke'. You say 'diesel fumes' but 'cigarette smoke'. That's just how it is.

Comment: I have heard (and seen) 'tobacco fumes'.